# Количество строк в файле

Tags: php, linux

Все привет ) Есть файл, открываю в Windows в Notepad++, там 1 млн. строк, как и надо.
Перекидываю файл на сервер, читаю его через `file_get_contents`, потом делаю `explode` входной строки, и размер, который мне показывается: 999512, но никак не 1000000.

А мне нужно прочитать абсолютно все строки.

**p.s.**  кодировка: utf-9 (без BOM), разделитель \r.

Comment: Решил эту, непонятную проблему  следующим способом: пере сохранил данные в csv, при помощи Excel и экспорта в CSV. Файл, видимо был совершенно непонятно формата, возможно были лишние символы.

Comment: UTF-**9**?

Comment: Ахахах )) Ага, новый формат. Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чудес не бывает. Варианты по убыванию.

- либо у Вас там есть разные разделители (к примеру ещё `\n`)
- либо в блокноте у Вас логические строки (если одна строка не влазит по длине на экран, то она разбивается на две (опция обычно называется "переносить длинные строки).
- может есть пустные строки, которые не посчитались.
- у пхп не хватило памяти и распарсил только 999512.

Первый вариант легко проверить, если есть доступ к консоли. просто запускаем `wc -l имяфайла` и смотрим. Но только эта команда показывает не кол-во строк (как может показаться), а кол-во переводов строк.
Последний вариант также легко проверяется - нужно просто распечатать пару последних строк и сверить.

Comment: wc -l показывает вообще 0 строк. И, кстати, открывая файл в mcedit, там весь контент одной строкой, разделенный видимо \r.

Comment: И еще, а как распечатать пару последних строк?

Comment: explode ведь сделали? значит все в виде массива. Вырезать часть элементов можно с помощью [array-slice](http://www.php.su/functions/?array-slice).

Comment: Конец файла совпадает. Я думаю, возможно где-то на разбита строка / строки? И состоит из нескольких значений.

Comment: Тогда Вам нужен метод поиска. Предлагаю такой.

    $data = explode(....);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $data+=100000) {
      print($data[$i]);
    }

То есть, печатаем каждую 100000 строку (всего получиться 9-10 строк). Потом открываете в блокноте и смотрите строки с теми же номерами (только помните - в пхп строки будут с 0 нумероваться, в блокноте - с 1). Найдете расхождение, переписываете цикл на такой

    $data = explode(....);
    for ($i = номер_строк,_где_правильно; $i < номер_строки,_где_уже_плохо; $data+=10000) {
      print($data[$i]);
    }

(шаг в 10 раз меньше).